# Find similar/related data, order by match count

Tags: mysql

My data is spread across multiple tables. Each table looks like:

```
id | value
```

And there's one master table:

```
id | type
```

Now I want to select all id's, for a given id, that have at least one value-match in one of the tables, ordered by the number of matches, descending.

Example:

```
TableMaster (id,type):
1,typeA
2,typeA
3,typeA
4,typeA
5,typeB

TableA (id,value):
1,A
2,B
3,B
4,C
5,D

TableB (id,value):
1,Y
2,X
3,X
4,X
5,X

TableC (id,value):
1,K
2,L
3,L
4,L
5,M
```

The wanted sql statement for **id=2** and **type=typeA** returns:

```
id
3 (1 match in TableA B=B, 1 match in TableB X=X, 1 match in TableC L=L => 3 matches)
4 (1 match in TableB X=X, 1 match in TableC L=L => 2 matches)
```

id=5 is not returned, because it's typeB.

Is there a efficient way to compare all tables without using a subselect for each table join and how do I count the matches, so I can use the value for ORDER BY?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query that you are using.

Comment: I don't have a query yet.